# How can I change the range of an axis on my colobar?

Tags: matplotlib

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr9Hq.png

I want to limit y to -5 to 5 instead of -200 to 200 or so. I guess I want to scale the y axis essentially.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with y-axis by `ylim` function.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

x = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=50)
y = np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=50)

N = 50
colors = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x,y,c=colors)
plt.xlim(0,1000) # This is to limit x-axis
plt.ylim(-5,5) # This is to limit y-axis
plt.grid()
```

[image: OutputImage]